# Watermark on Powerpoint slide

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am trying to put watermark on powerpoint slides using java but There was no hints were getting to do that. Is there any way to create watermark on ppt using apache-poi or any other opensource library in java.

Is it possible at all? Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Knowledgebase/Java/Spire.Presentation-for-Java/Program-Guide/Watermark/Java-insert-text-watermark-to-presentation-slides.html

Comment: When you say "watermark", do you simply mean a picture on the slidemaster?

Comment: @msbomrel it is not open source.

Comment: @kiwiwings I trying to do watermark text on slide

Comment: Ok, it looks like suggestive questions aren't your thing ...
Have a look at the [XSLF Cookbook](http://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html#SlideLayout). Here you see how to access the slide master. Add a image or text or what-have-you to the slide master and the elements you place on a normal slide usually (not always, in case you use placeholders) appear in front of the slidemaster elements. You can assign a different layout to the first page than the rest of the pptx. You can use a predefined pptx slidemaster or modify it on the fly ...